# Pasar el testigo en una carrera de relevos con Hilos

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas tengo un ejercicio de una carrera de relevos con hilos, y se tienen que pasar el relevo lo tengo montado pero nose como hacer el paso del relevo como tal, os dejo mi codigo y como se me ha ocurrido hacerlo

```
public class Atleta extends Thread {

    private String relevo;
    private static double tiempoT;

    public Atleta(String relevo) {
        super(relevo);
    }

    public Atleta() {
        tiempoT = 0;
    }

    public static double getTiempoT() {
        return tiempoT;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double tiempo = 0;
        synchronized (getClass()) {
            if (tiempoT == 0) {
                System.out.println("Comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                tiempoT += tiempo;
            } else {
                System.out.println("pasa el relevo y comienza a correr " + getName());
                tiempo = (double) (Math.random() * (11 - 9) + 9);
                tiempoT += tiempo;
            }
            System.out.println("el corredor: " + getName() + " ha tardado: " + tiempo);
        }
    }
}
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Atleta a1 = new Atleta("Pedro");
        Atleta a2 = new Atleta("Pablo");
        Atleta a3 = new Atleta("Usain");
        Atleta a4 = new Atleta("Manolo");
        a1.start();
        a1.join();
        a2.start();
        a2.join();
        a3.start();
        a3.join();
        a4.start();
        a4.join();
        System.out.println("final de la carrera, timepo total: " + Atleta.getTiempoT());
    }
}
```

Que opinais se pasa asi el testigo?lo pongo statico el objeto relevo?

Comment: No soy de java pero, el ultimo print, no seria `a1.GetTiempoT()`? porque creo que asi llamas al objeto pero vacio y sin haberlo iniciado

Comment: el objeto a1 ya esta creado y por tanto inicializado

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *pasar* el testigo? ¿Cuál es el *testigo*? Es decir, ¿es una variable? No veo referencia a ningún *testigo* en tu código. ¿Podrías aclarar ese punto? Saludos

Comment: Pues una carrera de relevo tiene un tetigo un palito que se pasan de unos aotro hasta que uno no te de le palito tu no puedes empezar a correr